# How would I display text under an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

First of all, I'm new here, and I really tried my best to get rid of the X/Y problem. I am trying to display some sort of loading text under a youtube embed. This is what I have tried so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#song1').hover(function() {
        $(this).html('rickroll <p id="song1load" style="position: absolute">Loading...</p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
        $(this).animate({
            maxHeight: '344px',
            height: '344px'
        })
    }, function() {
        $(this).html('rickroll')
        $(this).animate({
            maxHeight: '30px',
            height: '30px'
        })
    })
})
```

```css
body {
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
}

.video {
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 560px;
  width: 560px;
  max-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Koulen;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Resources/stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Koulen&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head> 
  <body>
    <div class="video" id="song1">rickroll<p id="song1load"></p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't think stackoverflow can load yt embeds in snippets, but you hopefully get my point. I'm open to any solutions!

Comment: You can see that when the yt embed partially loads (when it turns black) the loading text doesn't go away. there is probably a better way to put loading text in though

Comment: I can't tell if this is a question or an elaborate plan to rickroll Stack Overflow users

Comment: It isn't, rickroll is just a placeholder for what I did put lol.